Normalized Volume of Neighborhood in Projective Space
Bear with me since it's been awhile since I've done multivariate calculus and I seem to be pretty rusty.
Consider complex projective space $\mathbb{CP}^n$ with the Fubini-Study metric $d([u],[v]) = \arccos \vert u\cdot v \vert$. Then, my question is, under the uniform measure, what is the normalized volume of an $\varepsilon$ ball? I looked this up and found that this is known to be exactly $\sin^{2n-2}\varepsilon$ (for $\varepsilon < \pi/2$). I would like to be able to prove this myself though.
Here are my thoughts:
By mapping $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ the value I'm after is exactly the (normalized) surface area of the $\varepsilon$ neighborhood of a great circle on $S^{2n-1}$. Then, the (unnormalized) value should be $2\pi$ times the surface area of sections of other great circles, right?
To make this explicit, let us start with the $\varepsilon$ neighborhood of $S^1$ in $S^2$ (of course the dimensions are the wrong parity to correspond to complex space, but it seems illustrative to start here). In this case the (unnormalized) volume should be $2\pi*2\cos\varepsilon$, the $2\pi$ coming from integrating around $S^1$ and symmetry, the $2\cos\varepsilon$ from the cross-section of the neighborhood at a fixed point on $S^1$. Normalizing with the surface area of $S^2$ we get $\cos\varepsilon$.
I am struggling a bit to now generalize this to arbitrary (well, just even at the end of the day) dimensions. I believe where I'm messing up is dropping a surface area element in trying to integrate the cross-sections of $S^1$ in $S^{2n-1}$.
Thankful for any tips!

Welcome to MSE! <> The $\arccos$ definition of the Fubini-Study metric (i) perhaps should not have an absolute value, and (ii) without the absolute value looks like the round metric on the unit sphere (which in a nitpicky sense is not the Fubini-Study metric of complex geometry). Are you asking about F-S in this sense? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric#In_local_affine_coordinates
